# How can I select entries that have a string in them with SQLITE

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLite DB where I have a table which has a column called Support .

The support column has a list of values `(A,B,C,D)` however this list is a string not an array and the elements do not have a type.

I would like to select entries that have `A` in that list . But I couldn't use the `IN` operator with an inner query since it's a string and not an array .

I'm using SQLAlchemy, and it's docs says that MATCH doesn't work when using SQLite as backend, so How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you have a column called Support with strings like `A,B,C,D` and you want to select all the rows where the "list" of elements in Support contains `A`.

My first thought is you could use a wild card in your select statement. So in SQL that would be:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Support LIKE '%A%';
```

In SQLAlchemy this would be something like:

```
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.Support.like('%A%')).all()
```

Alternatively, you could just fetch all the data and filter the list in memory in Python. But, generally I think it's better to perform the filtering at the database level.